# How did the Space Shuttle prevent flying up when reentering the atmosphere?

Tags: space-shuttle, reentry, aerodynamics

Always when reentering the atmosphere, the shuttle was pitched up, right? When gliding through the [mesosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesosphere), how was it that it didn't fly up again then? Was it due to a certain distribution of weight within the orbiter?

Comment: Pitch and direction of flight are not related. Note that every airliner lands while being pitched upwards. In general, the nose of a plane never points down (exceptions apply)!

Comment: @asdfex well, they are related, but not simply. Angle of attack, airspeed, air density all matter.

Comment: The space shuttle did not so much as fly as do a Buzz Liteyear "Fall with style".

Comment: @asdfex This is because they're slow when landing. By flying a too heavy airliner too slow it's almost like a controlled stall that is applied for landing an airliner. But the shuttle glides at quite the highest speeds possible in the mesosphere.

Comment: What do you think would have made it "fly up"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble What makes _any_ plane fly up when pitching up not too much. SF's answer makes clear the shuttle pitched up _too much_ (about 40 deg) which has the opposite effect.

Comment: It's ridiculous to say it pitched up "too much". Compared to what?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Compared to an (in-atmosphere-)airplane e.g. an airliner that would stall in such circumstances and would want to avoid such pitch.

Comment: But since the shuttle wasn't an airliner, it used the proper pitch for its entry traj. Apples, oranges.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Indeed. It's just compared to standard airplanes because I wondered why it wouldn't fly up. A standard aircraft wouldn't fly up either, because such pitch would be 'too much' for that. It would stall. In case of the shuttle, this is exactly what it needed for gliding through the atmosphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesosphere stretches roughly from Kármán line (air pressure 0.0000003atm) down to about 50km altitude (air pressure: 0.001 atm) - in technology these amounts of air are typically thought of as "vacuum".

That means even despite the hypersonic speed, the lift generated by such minuscule amounts of air is very low. Additionally, it flew at an excessive angle of attack - about 40 degrees. The effect of that is drag force being roughly the same as the lift force, so the shuttle would rapidly lose speed, and in effect any chance to generate more lift through moving through denser air was lost, as loss of speed was kept at pace with growth of air density.

In short, it never reached air sufficiently dense at speed sufficiently high to produce enough lift to make it rise.

Comment: So it's the excessive angle of attack. I see. But the mesosphere's lower boundary isn't the Armstrong line (at 19 km / 12 mi) but the stratopause at 50 km / 31 mi. You probably meant 'mesospace'.

Comment: @Greenhorn corrected. Eh, confusing feet with meters, reading things off wrong paragraph on the wikipedia... I'm too tired today.

Comment: Why do you call the AOA "excessive"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Know of any airplanes or such using this sort of AOA in normal use? I don't recall more than 30 degrees is ever in use outside of dogfight and aerobation (and occasionally, moments before a disaster).

Comment: Apples, oranges.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Well, we're discussing why doesn't the shuttle behave in flight like common airplanes do.

Comment: @OrganicMarble For its purpose and requirements, sure. If you want, I can rephrase - 'extreme' or something along these lines.

Comment: No, it's fine. Just wondered why you thought it was 'excessive'.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Again, this was not meant as an "insult" or something to the Space Shuttle's pitch. It's just a matter of how to call it. "Excessive" is no more 'insulting' than "extreme". It's just a comparison with other planes.

Comment: @SF. with $\rho=$ 0.001 kg/m^3, $v=$ 7700 m/s, $A=$ 350 m^2 a very rough estimate of order of magnitude of aerodynamic force $\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 A$ is thirteen million Newtons. With a mass of 2 million kg that's many gees. In other words, at 0.001 atmosphere forces at orbital velocity are *huge!* Is it possible to show that at 0.001 atmospheres the velocity has already dropped so much that they can be dismissed by a wave of a hand rather than using mathematics?

Comment: @uhoh while I agree with the sentiment, an empty orbiter only weighed about 75,000 kg. You seem to be quoting the launchpad weight.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yikes, even worse! That's a factor of 27, goodness.

Comment: @uhoh: with AOA of 45 degrees, lift = drag exactly, so any gain of lift due to increase of air density would be offset by equivalent increase of drag and loss of speed; in short: a straight line descent trajectory. This is only 5 degrees off.

Comment: "the lift generated by such minuscule amounts of air is very low" Is it possible to define "minuscule" and "very low" with numbers? Right now it is impossible to judge if this prose-only answer is right or wrong.

Comment: It's correct that for the 40 deg AOA part of entry the orbiter's l/d was close to 1. However, below Mach 10, the AOA started to decrease and the l/d to climb. Supersonic l/d was around 2 at an AOA of around 10, subsonic around 4. https://i.imgur.com/Kz75ROh.png

Comment: Yep, transferring from aerobraking into glide.

Comment: The early part of entry was called the 'equilibrium glide'. Didn't use the term 'aerobraking'.